# What is the regex needed for locating a sequence starting with [ and ending with ]?

Tags: r, regex

Just as a warning this post contains profanity (apologies in advance).

In R I am trying to do a webscraping project with rap song lyrics. I have scraped lyrics from Wu Tang songs from a site called AZlyrics.

Let's say I have a two string of lyrics like this:-

```
string1 = "Bring da fuckin ruckus...[Chorus]"
string2 = "I scream on ya ass like your dad, bring it on...[Chorus][Verse Four: The Genius/GZA]"
```

I would like to remove `[....]` from my strings such that the two strings should become:

```
""Bring da fuckin ruckus..." 
"I scream on ya ass like your dad, bring it on..."
```

I have been trying to do this with

```
stringr::str_replace(string1, "\[.*?\]", "")
```

but I get this error:

> Error: '\[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\["

I am quite unfamiliar with how regex works so I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: amazing song but this question needs formatting to make it read a bit better :)

Comment: not sure why this is getting downvoted (failure to find previous answers?) The question is clearly stated and the OP made an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You need double-backslashes to escape properly.

```
re <- "(\\[[^]]*\\])+"
stringr::str_replace_all(string2, re, "")
```

- `(` begin group
- `\\[` literal open-bracket
- `[^]]*` zero or more instances of characters that are *not* `]`
- `\\]` literal close-bracket
- `+` one or more instances of group

A more challenging example:

```
str_replace_all('a [][adsfads] b [some]',re,"") ## "a  b "
```

`str_remove_all()` would be a slight improvement over "replace with blank"

Comment: Just an FYI: when you edited the post, you changed the question to include the \\, so right now it looks as if there is nothing wrong.

Comment: thanks.  The problem was moving the code from regular text to a code chunk.  Fixed now.

Comment: When I do `stringr::str_replace(string2, "\\[.*?\\]", "")
[1] "I scream on ya ass like your dad, bring it on...[Verse Four: The Genius/GZA]"`the second `[...]` is being missed. To match that too you need to include a quantifier expression: `stringr::str_replace(string2, "(\\[.*?\\]){1,}", "")`

Comment: Thank you so much! Apologies in the post. It was my first so I was surprised why when I wrote one \ in the textbox only 1 appeared in the display.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann see improvements